# Preguntas eliminadas

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Es correcto que un usuario elimine su pregunta cuando ya esta ha recibido respuesta. Pregunto ya que me paso recientemente y es algo molesto ya que inverti tiempo en responderle al usuario y este sin mas elimino su pregunta, por tanto el tiempo que inverti fue en vano.

Comment: Yo pregunté lo mismo hace tiempo, y la respuesta fue una porqueria, alegando que como la persona que pregunta tiene el "derecho" de eliminar su pregunta, no importa si usted invirtió todo el tiempo del mundo para responder esa pregunta, simplemente no les importa.

Comment: El problema es.. supongamos que recuperamos la publicacion.. que impide que el usuario la vuelva a eliminar? que puede llegar a pasar si directamente nunca acepta la respuesta? tal vez era una tarea y no quiere que su profesor la encuentre... Pudo eliminar la pregunta porque tu respuesta no llego a tener un voto. Desgraciadamente, esto es algo que puede llegar a pasar. Muchas veces, muchas preguntas no deben ser respondidas.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz que la respuesta que se te dio no fuera acorde a tu opinión no creo que sea suficiente para calificarla de "porquería". El sistema tiene ciertas condiciones para permitir eliminar una pregunta al autor de la misma, por ejemplo que no tenga respuestas o que las respuestas recibidas no hayan recibido un apoyo suficiente. Si una publicación y su respuesta no tiene votos positivos es que la comunidad no considera que ninguna de ambas son lo suficientemente relevantes para impedir al autor de la misma eliminarla. Este criterio es opinable, por supuesto, pero es propio de toda la red.

Comment: Todos hemos sentido frustración al invertir tiempo en una respuesta y que luego esta sea eliminada, pero por mi experiencia es importante tener en cuenta no responder preguntas mal formuladas o que no estén acordes a las normas del sitio, y de esa manera es mas difícil encontrarse en esa situación.

Comment: @gbianchi, entiendo todos los planteamientos y se que es complicado, pero igual uno siente molestias ya que invirtio tiempo en vano, cuando uno ve una pregunta que puede contestar le pasa como al gatito de la pelicula de shrek cuando dice: preguntame!!!, preguntame!!!(jeje). En mi caso particular prefiero evitar responder a usuarios que no estan registrados en el sitio pero no era el caso. Por si acaso aqui dejo el enlace de la publicacion eliminada https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/446155/recodificar-u-ordenar/446166#446166

Comment: Es decepcionante invertir tiempo en una respuesta y que el autor termine eliminando luego la pregunta, pero son las reglas del juego, así está diseñado el sistema y no veo mal que esto sea así, en particular por que el sistema, al mismo tiempo, no te impide reproducir nuevamente la pregunta original (mejorándola incluso) y autoresponderte. Con esto en definitiva, esta situación ha dejado de ser un problema.